# Changing year only in date in column with case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with end dates in different years and would like to change any year ending in '2004' to '4712'. The column is Date type and I keep getting an error

I have tried different codes and case statements but none of which worked

```
select
    case
        when h.EndDate like '2004%' then '4712%'
        else h.EndDate
    end as EndDate
from table h

1/31/2004
2/28/2004
3/31/2004
```

and so on would be the only years changed to:

```
1/31/4712
2/28/4712
3/31/4712
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would use `datefromparts()`:

```
select datefromparts(4712, month(h.enddate), day(h.enddate))
from h
where h.enddate >= '2014-01-01' and h.enddate < '2015-01-01';
```

In an update, this looks like:

```
update h
    set enddate = datefromparts(4712, month(h.enddate), day(h.enddate))
    where h.enddate >= '2014-01-01' and h.enddate < '2015-01-01';
```

Comment: datefromparts() was perfect as I couldn't use update. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `dateadd()`. `Like` works with string data type like varchar, nvarchar etc. When working with dates you need to use functions prepared to works with this data types (date, datetime etc.) To your date I added 2708 year which added to 4712.

```
update table
set EndDate = dateadd(year, 2708, EndDate)
where year(EndDate) = 2004
```